# How to handle reading and writing to the same socket

Tags: c#, sockets, stream, tcpclient

I establish a connection to my socket server and then start reading and writing data enormously. 
An exception occurs immediately:

**An exception of type 'System.InvalidOperationException' occurred in mscorlib.dll but was not handled in user code**

**Additional information: The stream is currently in use by a previous operation on the stream.**

How can I detect that

```
_reader.ReadLineAsync();
```

is currently receiving some data and I should wait with the writing and vice versa?

This class is used by a client that basically sends the received data from server back to the server.

```
public class TcpClientWorker2 
{
    private TcpClient _client;
    private Thread _t;
    private NetworkStream _networkStream;
    private StreamWriter _writer;
    private StreamReader _reader;
    public TcpClientWorker2()
    {
        var ipHostInfo = Dns.Resolve(Dns.GetHostName());
        var ipAddress = ipHostInfo.AddressList[0];

        _client = new TcpClient();
        _client.Connect(ipAddress, 10000);
        _t = new Thread(Run);
    }

    public async void Run()
    {
        _networkStream = _client.GetStream();
        _reader = new StreamReader(_networkStream);
        _writer = new StreamWriter(_networkStream) { AutoFlush = true };
        while (true)
        {
            var data = await _reader.ReadLineAsync();
            //perform callback (send the data immediately back to server)
        }
    }

    public void Start()
    {
        _t.Start();
    }
    public async Task Send(string text)
    {
        await _writer.WriteLineAsync(text);
    }
}
```

Comment: You're *supposed* to read and write network streams at the same time. I suspect that your code may be writing at the same time another thread is writing, which is a recipe for failure. Please post the stack trace for your error.

Comment: Yes, that is correct I am writing from a differend thread. How can I write from the same thread when .ReadLineAsync is blocking?

Comment: you can have a different reader and writer thread. You just gotta make sure there is only one thread reading and one thread writing.

Answer (score 2):

From this source you get confirmation :
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.sockets.networkstream%28v=vs.110%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396

> Read and write operations can be performed simultaneously on an instance of the NetworkStream class without the need for synchronization. As long as there is one unique thread for the write operations and one unique thread for the read operations, there will be no cross-interference between read and write threads and no synchronization is required.

We can see in your code that there is only one thread reading, but there is no confirmation in your code that there is only one thread writing.
That is the part you should investigate further.